# Should I be using a 1:n or m:n relation when connecting an Object to other Objects of the same type?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

This is in regards to SQL (Oracle PL/SQL if that makes a difference).

I've got a custom Object of the type User. A user has two columns:

- Name (VARCHAR2), just a normal String
- Friends

His friends are other Users. I am thinking of using a nested table here, but I am wondering: is this a 1:n or m:n relation? I think this can be modeled with 1:n, since every of those n users themselves have n other connections.

Comment: [PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) is Oracle's in-database programming language, not a flavour of SQL.

Comment: Also, objects have *attributes* and *methods*. Tables have columns. It's not clear whether your "custom object" is a table (with columns) or a type (with attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the terminology. User is an Object with two attributes: Name (varchar) and Friends (nested table of type User)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the following is true:

- One user can have multiple friends.
- One user can be friends of multiple other users.

That makes this an n:m relationship.

The recommended way to implement such a relationship is with an association/junction table.  Also, I would also recommend ids.  The model would look something like:

```
create table users (
    user_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    name varchar2(255)
    createdAt date not null
);

create table friends (
    friend_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    user_1 int not null references users(user_id),
    user_2 int not null references users(user_id),
    unique (user_1, user_2),
    createdAt date not null
);
```

I wouldn't recommend nested tables.  They are not designed for referential integrity.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. Under referential integrity I assume you mean trailing/dead data on deletion? What about performance, would nested tables be more performant?

Comment: @n0stalghia . . . Referential integrity does not refer only to deleted records.  A foreign key constraint (in general) guarantees that a value in the referring column refers to a valid value in the reference table.